# Ruby: how to know depth of multidemensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my problem I have met in my assignment.

- Array A has two elements: array B and array C.
- Array B has two elements: array D and array E
- At some point, array X just contains two elements: string a and string b.

I don't know how to determine how deep array A is. For example:

```
arrA = [
         [
           [1,2]
         ]
       ]
```

I have tested by: `A[0][0][0] == nil` which returns `false`. Moreover, `A[0][0]..[0] == nil` always returns `false`. So, I cannot do this way to know how deep array A is.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545613/getting-dimension-of-multidimensional-array-in-ruby

Comment: can you provide a better example? `arrA` looks nothing like you describe in words.

Comment: Can't you just recursively check the type for array-ness and while it's an array keep doing so?

Comment: Please tag homework questions as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting dimension of multidimensional array in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545613/getting-dimension-of-multidimensional-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is not what you're looking for, it should be a good starting point:

```
def depth (a)
  return 0 unless a.is_a?(Array)
  return 1 + depth(a[0])
end

> depth(arrA)
=> 3
```

Please note that this only measures the depth of the first branch.

Answer (score 5):

My solution which goes below answers the maximum depth of any array:

Example: for arr=**[** [[1],[2,3]], **[[[** 3,4 ]]] ], the maximum depth of arr is **4** for 3,4.

Aprroach - flatten by one level and compare

```
b, depth = arr.dup, 1

until b==arr.flatten
  depth+=1
  b=b.flatten(1)
end
puts "Array depth: #{depth}" #=> 4
```

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

A simple pure functional recursive solution:

```
def depth(xs, n=0)
  return case
  when xs.class != Array
    n
  when xs == []
    n + 1
  else
    xs.collect{|x| depth x, n+1}.max
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
depth([]) == 1
depth([['a']])) == 2
depth([1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, [[2, 2],[]], 4, 5, 6, 7], 5, 5, [[[[[3, 4]]]]], [[[[[[[[[1, 2]]]]]]]]]]) == 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner similar to [kiddorails' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863610/2771889) extracted into a method:

```
def depth(array)
  array.to_a == array.flatten(1) ? 1 : depth(array.flatten(1)) + 1
end
```

It will flatten the array 1 dimension at the time until it can't flatten anymore, while counting the dimensions.

Why is this better than other solutions out there?

- doesn't require modification to native classes (avoid that if possible)
- doesn't use metaprogramming (`is_a?`, `send`, `respond_to?`, etc.)
- fairly easy to read
- works on hashes as well (notice `array.to_a`)
- *actually works (unlike only checking the first branch, and other silly stuff)*

Answer (score 0):

Also one line code if you want to use

```
   def depth (a)
        a.to_s.count("[")
    end
```

Comment: It will not work for this case: `[ [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ]`.